# How to validate form in execute method not in validate?

Tags: validation, struts2

I want to validate form in execute() method not in validate() and display error message in website. From some reasons I can't use validate method. I want to do something like this:

```
@Override
public String executeAction() throws Exception {
    ...
        if(bean.getDbErrorBean().getErrorType() != 0) {
            **addFieldError("numberX", bean.getDbErrorBean().getErrorMsg());**

            return NONE;
        } else {
            LOG.info("############### OK!");
        }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: so are you facing any issue while doing this?

Comment: when i return NONE, error message are not displayed

Comment: @TomaszGutkowski:Returning `ActionSupport.NONE` (or null) from an action class method causes the results processing to be skipped i belive you need to send either ERROR or say INPUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding answer so as to make the solution more clear to other who have same issue or trying to do same thing.

`ActionSupport.NONE` (or null) from an action class method causes the results processing to be skipped.

For more information about result configuration please refer [Struts2 result-configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/result-configuration.html)